# Why am I getting sun.misc.Contended symbol cannot find error?

Tags: java, maven, java-9

I've got a very simple program:

`Test.java`:

```
package com;
import sun.misc.Contended;
public class Test {
}
```

and `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

when I put `mvn compile` I've got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project proj: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/john/Desktop/proj/src/main/java/com/Test.java: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Contended
[ERROR] location: package sun.misc
```

Why?

Comment: are you using java 9 ?

Comment: Yes. I edited. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `sun.misc` moved to [`jdk.internal.misc`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137056) and they are private package to JDK.

> ... friend interfaces should be moved out of 'sun.misc'
>   and located in a truly private package. This is so that they are not
>   part of the proposed to be exported 'sun.misc' package.

You can use `--add-exports` and `--add-opens` to gain access to internal API.

In your case, you can add following in your `pom.xml`

```
<compilerArgs>
   <arg>--add-exports</arg>
   <arg>java.base/jdk.internal.misc=<<your.module>></arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Please note, you need to change `<<your.module>>` to your actual module name.

Reference : - *[JEP-261:Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)*

Comment: so how to use it? I would like to use @Contended annotation.

Comment: @Gilgamesz Please go through the link. You will also understand the risk.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, I am confused: Here http://beautynbits.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/the-end-for-false-sharing-in-java.html someone describes that as a great Java feature. Then, the Java makes in unavailable by default. What's going on?

Comment: @Gilgamesz you could try my updated post. Also, I'm not sure, but it seems like they are moving everything from `sun` :D

Comment: Thanks for your response.